# Assuming $ab^2 = b^3a$ and $a^2=1$ prove that the order of $b$ is $5$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $a,b \in G$ with $a \ne 1$ and $b \ne 1$. Assuming $ab^2 = b^3a$ and $a^2=1$ I need to prove that the order of $b$ is $5$.

I have proved by contradiction that it can't be 2 or 3 but I don't know how to prove that it must be 5 and it can't be 4.

Comment: Why can't it be 6 or 7, for example?  Do you anything about the order of $G$ itself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that 
$$b^5 = b^3a^2b^2=(b^3a)(ab^2)=(b^3a)(b^3a)=b^3(ab^2)ba=b^3(b^3a)ba=b^6aba,$$
multiplying by $b^{-5}$ from the left we get $1=baba$. Multiplying by $a$ from the right we get $a=baba^2=bab$. Thus 
$$1=a^2=(bab)^2=b(ab^2)ab=b(b^3a)ab=b^4a^2b=b^4\cdot 1 \cdot b = b^5.$$

Comment: How would you proof the order is not 4?

Comment: @Rodrigo Because 4 does not divide 5.

Comment: Well there is a general fact that if $x^n=1$ then the order of $x$ divides $n$. In our case $b^5=1$ and so the order of $b$ divides $5$ and so is equal to either $1$ or $5$. However $b\neq 1$ so the order of $b$ must equal $5$.

Answer (score 5):

Consider that $$ab^2a=b^3$$ And so:
$$b^2=ab^3a=ab^2ba=ab^2aaba=b^3aba$$ From here: $$b^{-1}=aba$$ Thus $$b^{-2}=ab^2a=b^3$$ which means:  $$b^5=1$$

Comment: How would you proof the order is not 4?

Comment: Since $b^5=1$ and $5$ is a prime number.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, $a^2=1\Rightarrow 
a=a^{-1},$ so, $$\begin{aligned}ab^2&=b^3a\\\Rightarrow b^2&=ab^3a=(aba)^3\\b^3&=ab^2a=(aba)^2\\\Rightarrow b^4&=(b^2)^2=((aba)^3)^2=((aba)^2)^3=(b^3)^3=b^9\Rightarrow b^5=e.\end{aligned}$$

And, an alternative way of proving $|b|=5:$ $e=b^5=b(b^4)=b^2(b^3),$ so $b^4=e\Leftrightarrow b=e$ and $b^3=e\Leftrightarrow b^2=e\Leftrightarrow e=b^3=b(b^2)=be=b.$